Why does Coverity show fixed defects and FP's as still-outstanding defects?
I'm using Coverity Scan with an OSS project.  Most of the issues found are FP's or by-design, a few are genuine issues.  In all cases they've been classified as FP, intentional, or fixed.  However Coverity is still listing them as "Outstanding Defects" even though there's no defect there.  Is there some magic toggle you have to flip on issues to tell Coverity to stop treating, say, a FP as an outstanding defect?
Currently for FP's, for example, I'm setting Classification = FP, Severity = Insignificant, Action = Ignore but they're still showing as outstanding defects even though there's no defect there.
Edit: Screenshot of the main dashboard.

Screenshot of the "Outstanding defects" tab (note also that the count doesn't match the dashboard value):

This is sorted by date so it shows that there are issues that were closed over ten years ago which Coverity still marks as outstanding issues.
For reference, if I look at "Issues: Project Scope" I get a bit over 200, so just over half are correctly marked as closed and the rest are (incorrectly) marked as still open.  I haven't been able to identify any pattern in closed vs. (incorrectly) non-closed issues.
Second edit: Screenshot of another dashboard showing False Positives and Intentional as open issues, which may be the cause of the problem:


Sure, see the edited original question.  And in terms of the counts not matching I am aware of this particular issue.

If you click on the little "gear" icon to the right of "Outstanding Defects", what are the view filter settings?

The filter settings are at the default level, i.e. nothing is selected in any of the categories Action, Category, Checker, CID, Classification ...Type.  Group By is set to None (default setting) and Show Occurrences is unchecked (also default).  From the Info dialog:
View Name:Outstanding Defects
View Type:Issues: By Snapshot
Filters
No filters applied to view
Snapshot Scope
Show: last()
Not including outdated streams

Added another screenshot, it could be that it's counting FPs and Intentional issues as Outstanding Defects.

In the question, there are two counts of "Outstanding Defects":

The dashboard with "79 Outstanding Defects".

The total of "95 Issues match" in the lower-left corner of the "Outstanding Defects" view including issues marked as False Positive or Intentional.


Count 1: Outstanding Defects dashboard count
The reason for the wrong dashboard count is that it includes issues reported in components that have been configured as "Ignore in analysis".  This seems like a bug; I'll file one.
The workaround is to change the component configurations so none are ignored.

From the dashboard, click on the project name.
Click on Analysis Settings.
Click "Remove" next to all of the components with "ignore".
Re-create them without checking the "ignore" box.  (There's no way to just change that setting by itself, sadly.)
Click "Save changes".
Wait a while?  The UI says 15 minutes but it seemed to take effect within a minute when I tried it.
Close any open defects view tab since it seems to retain some stale info.
Click "View defects" (from the project overview) to re-open the defects list.

Then the Outstanding Defects view, as edited per the instructions below, should show a total that matches what is shown in the dashboard (79 in your case).  You may want to change the view setting and enable the "Component" column, if it is not already shown, to see how issues are partitioned into components.
Count 2: Outstanding Defects view total
In a comment below the question, the view settings for "Outstanding Defects" are further given:

From the Info dialog: View Name:Outstanding Defects View Type:Issues: By Snapshot Filters No filters applied to view Snapshot Scope Show: last() Not including outdated streams

The "No filters applied" is the key here.  In the Coverity Connect UI, a "view" is essentially a data source (e.g., issues in a snapshot), a collection of filters, a set of columns to display, and a few other details like the sort order.  The view attributes can be changed by the user that owns the view, and are persistently saved in the server's database.
There should be a default view called "Outstanding Issues" with the following filter settings shown by clicking the "i" icon and editable by clicking the "gear" icon:

View Name: Outstanding Issues
View Type: Issues: By Snapshot
Filters

Classification: Unclassified,Pending,Bug
Issue Kind: Quality,Security (which is in practice equivalent to not filtering on this attribute; it is a historical relic)


Snapshot Scope

Show: last()
Not including outdated streams



Crucially, the Classification filter will cause issues marked as FP or Intentional to not be shown in the list.  Thus the fix for the first issue is to change the view filter settings to what is shown above.
In the screenshot, the view is called "Outstanding Defects".  I think that is what this view as called in an older version of the product, and that name was persisted across upgrades (correctly, because it is user-configurable).
Tangent: The documentation for the Issues: By Snapshot view type says:

Outstanding Issues: Issue Kind filter is set to Quality, and the Status filter is set to New and Triaged.

But this is wrong (outdated), as the default view for a new account uses Classification rather than Status (and includes both Issue Kinds).  Furthermore, in my experimentation, the Status filter seems to be broken, producing nonsensical lists of issues; do not use it.

Thanks!  So I've (re)set the filters to View Name: Outstanding Defects View Type: Issues: By Snapshot Filters   Issue Kind: Quality   Status: New,Triaged [...], after this Outstanding Defects shows two closed (i.e. not actually outstanding) issues, one from 2018 and one from a few weeks ago, and the Dashboard is unchanged from the original screenshot I posted, 79 Outstanding Defects (should be zero).

What do you mean by "closed"?  That isn't a term used in the UI as far as I can tell.

I've been experimenting with the Scan UI, and the Status filter seems possibly broken.  Also the documentation is wrong, as the default view for a fresh account filters on Classification, not Status, and that seems to work better.  Can you try changing the view filter?  Remove the filter on Status, and instead filter for Classification is Unclassified, Pending, or Bug.  Then what do you see?
